# AVFoundation framework not showing permission popup in iOS 10

Tags: swift3

I am using following code in viewdidload method.And app crashes when I Open app.Please let me know what I am doing wrong.Thanks in advance.

```
 recordingSession = AVAudioSession.sharedInstance()
    do {
        try recordingSession.setCategory(AVAudioSessionCategoryPlayAndRecord)
        try recordingSession.setActive(true)
        recordingSession.requestRecordPermission() { [unowned self] allowed in
            DispatchQueue.main.async {
                if allowed {
                    self.loadRecordingUI()
                } else {
                    // failed to record!
                }
            }
        }
    } catch {
        // failed to record!
    }
```

Comment: What is the crash says in xCode console ? Did you added necessary persmission in your plist already for audio

Comment: I forgot to add NSMicrophoneUsageDescription key in plist.Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You have to add `NSMicrophoneUsageDescription` in your plist file to get the permission popup.

For the list of permissions check [this SO answers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39465687/nscamerausagedescription-in-ios-10-0-runtime-crash/39488067#39488067)