# Generate .IPA with Xcode

Tags: ios, xcode, ipa

I am trying to finalize my iOS application, the problem I encounter is that I can not generate file .IPA file export from the archive that is created.
When I deploy the application directly to a device, the application works, as well as in an emulator.

I do not have a distributor account on Apple, I use my iTunes account as a developer account.

Is there a way to generate the .IPA file so that I can share my application so that others can test it?

I thank you in advance :)

Comment: what's the error message you are getting while exporting .ipa from archive?Check Console while exporting .ipa then you'll be able to solve root cause.

Comment: I believe you can find the answer at an existing post:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25970741/how-to-create-ipa-in-xcode-6

or

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25970741/how-to-create-ipa-in-xcode-6

Answer (score 2):

Edit your app **Scheme**, Go to **Run**

Select **Info** Tab and Change the **build configuration** from debug to release,

it will help you to encounter your issue.

[image]

[image]

Quick Solution, goto **archive** section and change configuration to debug. it will allow you to generate .IPA

Comment: I managed to generate the IPA, but when I want to install with itunes, the application disappears: / I do not understand why ..

Comment: thats another issue. you have to check your privacy description, here is the list of all privacy description, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39465687/nscamerausagedescription-in-ios-10-0-runtime-crash

Answer (score 0):

For internal testing purpose, you can drag .app file from Products folder of XCode after running app on device as target & drop into iTunes Connect. Get .ipa file by Right Click on app icon in Apps section of iTunes .Select Show In Finder.