# Ionic App in Xcode giving this error NSCameraUsageDescription is not set in the info.plist?

Tags: ios, xcode, ionic-framework, camera, barcode

`Ionic` App giving this error in Xcode:

`NSCameraUsageDescription is not set in the info.plist`.

And Barcode scanner is not opening in `Ios` Devices.

Why is it so?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/39608545/4725893 This worked for me.