# Privacy Camera Description issue in info.plist

Tags: ios

I'm making an app in which there is camera usage. I have added the key `Privacy - Camera Usage Description` and I have added the description also with it. "Use camera to display ARKit content."

But when I run the app it crashes my app with this error:

> This app has crashed because it attempted to access privacy-sensitive data without a usage description.  The app's Info.plist must contain an NSCameraUsageDescription key with a string value explaining to the user how the app uses this data.

I'm confused why I'm getting this error since I have added it in the Info.plist.

Comment: Please review [these search results](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=must+contain+an+NSCameraUsageDescription+key+with+a+string+) on the error.

Comment: Duplicate Questions: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39465687/nscamerausagedescription-in-ios-10-0-runtime-crash

Comment: Possible duplicate of [NSCameraUsageDescription in iOS 10.0 runtime crash?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39465687/nscamerausagedescription-in-ios-10-0-runtime-crash)

Comment: use this : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39631256/request-permission-for-camera-and-library-in-ios-10-info-plist/47970037#47970037

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try below things,

1. Delete app from Simulator or Device
2. Press <kbd>Cmd</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>K</kbd> to clean the project and <kbd>Cmd</kbd> + <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>K</kbd> to clean the build directory
3. Remove Derived Data folder
4. Quit and restart Xcode

FYI. Just give it a try.